# How to fix 'Multiple blocks of same type on page, sharing data on edit()'?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I started block development recently and I just came across a problem. Let say I create one block twice on a page. I edit that block. As soon as I click the second block it takes the over the same data as the first. On preview the behaviour is the same but if I now refresh the editor page both blocks are treated seperatly. What am I missing out?

I added unique ID's but that did not help. I rewrote my data structure aswell.

Sadly there are no error messages. All I know that updating one value will trigger the callbacks of all the blocks of the same type. The state is only updated for the selected one.

Comment: gif showing the problem:https://imgur.com/a/tvVO7GN

Comment: Please also share the code of your block.